# Combinations of array elements

Tags: arrays, arraylist, groovy

May be similar question is asked in the past, but i was not able to find a solution for my problem. I have an 2d array of integers like this `{{1,2,3},{7,5},{4,9}}`, i want to get all the possible combinations for the array elements.

Output should be - 
`{{1,7,4},{1,7,9},{1,5,4},{1,5,9},{2,7,4},{2,5,9},{3,7,4},{3,5,9}}`

Can anyone help  me in this ?

Comment: I'm stuck in taking the first step itself. How to start iterating over the array elements in order to create combinations

Comment: Try googling, lot's of tutorial available there. Just apply your logic to code, it ll done. look https://community.oracle.com/thread/1249682#discussion-5244008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In groovy (which I assume you want):

```
[[1,2,3],[7,5],[4,9]].combinations()
```

Comment: There is also a convenient way to work on each of those combination (avoiding to iterate over it again). `[[1,2,3],[7,5],[4,9]].eachCombination { println it }`. Enjoy.. @ShashankShekhar